# In Erlang, passing a message to all elements of a list of pids

Tags: foreach, erlang, list-comprehension, message-passing, lambda-calculus

I am trying to build a very simple barrier-synchronization server, where the server is initially fed a number of processes that will be communicating with it. When a process is done, it receives a message with that process' Pid, and it keeps a list of every process to do so. When the barrier reaches zero (all processes have sent messages), my server needs to send a message to each of these (I am using `[Pid | ProcList]` as my list of pids).

I have tried using a helper function to no avail, list comprehensions keep me in an infinite loop, and as such I am looking into how to use lists:foreach to take care of this.
I am fairly new to functional programming, but from what I understand, this foreach needs to take in the list as well as a lambda-calculus function to send a message to each node in the list. Due to the infix nature of "!", I have yet to find a way to do this without causing syntax errors.

Answer (score 4):

How you've made infinite loop in list comprehension? I must say, that's quite challenging. Try this:

```
Message = % broadcast message goes here
ListOfPids = % list of recipients
[Pid ! Message || Pid <- ListOfPids].
```

If you want to use `foreach`, than it takes one argument function as first argument, so need to wrap `send` first, as it is two argument function.

```
Message =  % broadcast message goes here
ListOfPids = % list of recipients
Fun = fun (Pid) -> Pid ! Message end,
lists:foreach(Fun, ListOfPids).
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! And I realized I phrased that backwards; my helper functions kept me in an infinite loop and I had been trying list Comprehension to no avail...
The code snippet that I have that it is freezing on right now is as follow:
        Message = {self(),continue},
        io:format("got here 1"),
        [X ! Message || X <- Pids],
                                                                io:format("got here 2");
Freezing between 1 and 2... I guess this means it's a problem with the processes I am communicating with. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @JBarnett I can't help you. You showed me just a short fragment of your code and i can't tell why it doesn't work. There is no way to freeze in here, as it's just sending messages.  If your code is short make an edit to your question. EDIT: Is there any error? If Pids is not a list or X is not pid then this should crash... are you monitoring those processes somehow? If you know its pid, then try is_process_alive(ItsPid).